# Determine and update the openssl version on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

Recently, [Sectigo's root certificate expired](https://support.sectigo.com/Com_KnowledgeDetailPage?Id=kA03l00000117LT), which caused troubles to openssl clients [whose version is less than 1.1.1](https://www.cmu.edu/iso/service/cert-auth/addtrust.html).

About the same time, we started to experience issues with SSL connections in our application, which is hosted on Amazon AWS Lambda. We cannot reproduce the SSL issues locally on our development machines. The failing environments use AWS lambda with dotnetcore3.1 runtime. From [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html), the associated operating system is Amazon Linux 2.

So, my guess is that the Amazon Linux 2 VM backing AWS Lambda is using an openssl version less than 1.1.1, which breaks SSL validation following the Sectigo certificate expiration.

However, I can't find a way to check the version of the openssl package which is shipped in our Lambda. I would like to ensure that the openssl version is the real cause of our issue, and temporarily update it if necessary until Amazon fixes the issue and updates its lambda VMs.

How can we check the openssl version shipped in our lambda? How can we update it (temporarily, until Amazon fixes the issue), ideally by updating our cloudformation template?

Comment: Could your Lambda function invoke `openssl version` via a system call, or use lambdash? You won't be able to update the OS of the Lambda environment - it's a managed service.

Comment: Why do you want to update the OpenSSL version? If you can update it, and choose to update it, do you also intend to maintain it and keep up with new OpenSSL security fixes that come out every month or so?

Comment: @jarmod I tried using dotnet's `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` to do exactly what you suggested, but failed to get any result (although it works locally). That's one of the reasons I'm asking this here, out of despair :/

Comment: @omajid I want to check and manage openssl myself temporarily because apparently [Amazon failed](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=945347) to include a non-obsolete version in its Amazon Linux 2 VM (which is used by lambda), which results in multiple SSL connections failing in production following the global [Sectigo certificate issue](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2020/06/02/the-mystery-of-the-expiring-sectigo-web-certificate/), including the SMTP connection to our mail provider.